# Where can I find the Xlint option in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I get an error `Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` in Netbeans. Where can I find the option to uncheck?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't "uncheck" that option, you need to add the `-Xlint:unchecked` parameter to the parameters passed to the Java compiler.

For Ant based projects, this is done through `Project Properties -> Build -> Compiling` in the "Additional compiler options" input field at the bottom of the dialog (where it says "*e.g.: -Xlint:unchecked*")

[image]

For Maven projects see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449314)

Comment: Remember to uncheck compile on save to see the warning every time you run file.

Comment: Yeah, the corollary to the comment by @GusDeCooL is that if you want to see these warnings explained just the first time, try a Clean & Build, rather than just Run.  They'll show then, but not on any subsequent run.  The nasty thing is, you don't even get the warning to turn on -Xlint:unchecked once you've set it.  So if you only "Clean & Build" on occasion, that'll be the only time you'll see any of the lint warnings!  Caveat Lector (can't say Emptor, cause NetBeans is FOSS)!

Comment: Why is this not automatically unchecked? Is there any harm in always leaving it unchecked?

Comment: For a Netbeans maven project you will need to set the flag in the pom.xml see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449251/how-to-compile-using-xlintunchecked-in-a-maven-project

Comment: @Aner, +1 for helping with maven projects.  Alas, neither the linked page, nor the checked answer links still work.   I just get errors from maven saying that the arg is invalid.   If I find a solution I will post it back here.

Comment: @Teto: if you find an answer for Maven, add it to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12449251/330315 not this one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.   Thanks, for that suggestion.  I have added a comment to the checked solution on that question which adds clarity (I hope).

Comment: This is not possible in current Netbeans, as of version 12.2.

Comment: @JN01: that option is still there. Are you sure you are using an Ant based project?

Comment: Oh darn, it doesn't say Ant here. Maven project at hand.
Note for anyone stumbling this far: This answer applies to "Java with Ant" project. Not "Java with Maven" and possibly not "Java with Gradle" projects.

Comment: @JN01: see Aner's comment from July 21, 2016

Answer (score 0):

`-Xlint` is a JVM parameter. In your project follow this steps:

1. Project properties
2. Run
3. VM Options

And there in the text field you write `-Xlint:unchecked`