# Eclipse not showing deprecated warning?

Tags: java, android, deprecated

As per Javadocs:

```
public Date (int year, int month, int day) 
This constructor was deprecated in API level 1.

Date date = new Date(year,month,date);
```

This constructor was deprecated in API Level 1 but my Eclipse isn't giving me deprecation warning in the Android project I'm creating. What can be the issue? Is there a silly mistake that I'm making?

- I've compiled the project at `4.0` version.
- I've checked the Lint preferences and it's fine.
- I've not set an `@SuppressWarnings`, so that is ruled out.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Calendar mCalen = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = mCalen.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = mCalen.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = mCalen.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                String newDate = new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth)
                        .append("/").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("/")
                        .append(year).toString();
                date = null;
                timeStamp = null;
                dateStamp = 0;
                date = newDate;
                timeStamp = new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                dateStamp = timeStamp.getTime();
                dateTextView.setText(date);
            }
        }, year, month, day);
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of Settings]

Comment: You can manually check deprecated errors by,

Right click project>Android tools>Run Lint : Check for common errors

Comment: @Harshit Rathi Bhai no help so far, i've gone through Eclipse docs, set everything properly but still no output.

Comment: Provide screenshot of your code.

Comment: @Harshit Rathi Bro the code is there in my post and it is as good as a screenshot.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior i want to see screenshot of your code because which type of deprecated import you use.

Comment: @Harshit Rathi U mean u wanna see the imports?

Comment: @Harshit Rathi See the updated post.

Comment: have u tried with project properties.

Comment: @Harshit Rathi Yep, i tried everything that i could find before posting it on StackOverflow. One thing i would like to tell you, It's not showing deprecation in Android project but when i create a simple Java project it gives me the deprecation warning in the very same Eclipse I'm using.

Comment: have you check with android lint preferences also.

Comment: @Harshit Rathi Everything is fine. I've mentioned that earlier only.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

```
Preferences | Java | Compiler | Errors/Warnings | Deprecated and Restricted API
```

Make sure **Deprecated API** is set to Warning. Ensure the code which is deprecated has a @Deprecated annotation either at the class / method or in the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

Check for following:

```
Properties > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Deprecated and restricted API
```

Select `Warning` for Deprecated API.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that setting is already there and active.

Comment: Are you adding project specific Error/Warning, If so please remove it by unchecking "Enable Project Specific Setting" from Right click on your project and go in project properties >Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings

Comment: No it isn't project specific, it's common settings to whole of the eclipse.

Comment: have you got any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to turned on warnings of your related project from project properties. To do this follow these steps:

1. Right click on your project and go in project properties.
2. Select Java Compiler tab and expand it.
3. Now you see error/warning tab. Now enable that check box and change project setting.

or remove check box from project specific error/warnings settings and click on Android Lint Preferences tab and search for deprecated Serverity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that setting is already there and active.

Comment: provide an screen shot of that setting.

Comment: go in project properties through right click on project not from preference settings and check my edited answer.

Comment: have you tried with project properties or from preference setting and check my edited answer.