# How to fix "uses or overrides a deprecated API." for my PageAdapter?

Tags: java

i have a problem of compilation. When i want to run my app, she don't compil. Error in method PageAdapter, in the line: super(fm)

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int[] colors;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int[] colors) {
        super(fm);
        this.colors = colors;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return(3);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return(PageFragment.newInstance(position, this.colors[position]));
    }
```

When i run my app, she say me:

uses or overrides a deprecated API.

C:\Users\NyCko\AndroidStudioProjects\MyNews\app\src\main\java\com\fossourier\nicolas\mynews\Adapters\PageAdapter.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311964/warning-message-uses-or-overrides-a-deprecated-api-encountered-during-code-com

Comment: That's only a warning, not an error message. Your app should still compile (unless there's some other error). But you should fix this warning anyway - why don't you recompile with -Xlint just as the warning tells you to do?

Comment: From (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter): This class was deprecated in API level 27.1.0.
Use FragmentPagerAdapter instead.